# Gnome shell with desktop icons without unity file manager

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with gnome3-shell (top taskbar)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73482/problem-with-gnome3-shell-top-taskbar)

I have new Ubuntu 11.10 and I installed gnome-shell instead Unity. I want to add some icons to desktop, but when I enable file manager to handle the desktop in Ubuntu tweak I get file manager panel under the Gnome shell main panel.

Is there way to delete this file manager panel and still have icons on the desktop?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What I see in the screenshot is just the file manager menu, which, along with other menus shows in the top panel by default. AFYI, Unity uses the same file manager as Gnome Shell, it's called Nautilus. Do not remove it!

What you need to do is remove the Global Menu integration:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt
```

For Firefox, either disable the Global Menu addon:

```
“Tools -> Add-ons -> Extensions”. Disable the “Global Menu Bar Integration” extension
```

or remove it: `sudo apt-get purge firefox-globalmenu`.

Answer (score 0):

Mabye removing appmenu-gtk3 and restarting nautilus will solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3
nautilus -q
```